# "What are the two?" VS "What are they?" VS "What are those?"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, pronouns

Someone is interviewing people on the streets of London. One of them is like this:

*A: How many languages do you speak?*

*B: Two.*

*A: What are the two?*

The question **"What are the two?"** sounds unusual or different to me. I think it is the shortened form of "What are the two languages that you said you spoke."

However, I also thought I would not have structured the question that way. For instance, instead of **"What are the two?"**, Can we say **"What are they?"** or **"What are those?"**?

Comment: I would say "Which [languages] are they?"

Comment: Or even "Which two?"